# Como posso criar funções de sequencia e series matematicas no python?

Tags: python, loop

Como posso fazer para o interpreter entender o que é o valor anterior de uma função matemática, como por exemplo: "Xn = 3,7(xn-1)" onde "n-1" significa o resultado da operação anterior do loop. Meio difícil de entender mas isso é nada menos que uma sequencia e serie matemática, mas queria aplicar ao python para resolver problemas matemáticos.

Comment: Leia sobre recursividade.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

São duas formas:

1) a mais fácil - é não tentar usar a notação matemática, e traduzir tudo o que for da notação matemática para a linguagem que você está usando, no caso o Python 
. (Se for pensar, a notação que usamos para matemática é um tipo de linguagem de programação também)

Nesse caso, `equacao = "Xn = 3,7(xn-1)";` tenta denotar uma função que depende do resultado da série anterior. Esses casos, conseguimos resolver em programação estruturada com o uso de funções recursivas - mas sempre é necessário um critéri de parada que você não deu. Assumindo que o critério sej "X1 = 1", a expressçao acima pode ser escrita como a função em Python:

```
def X(n):
   if n == 1:
       return 1
   return 3.7 * X(n - 1)
```

Ou seja, exatamente como no caso da notação matemática, a função usa o resultado dela mesma numa iteração anterior. A diferença para matemática, é que em matemática tendemos a ver "ok, eu imagino que o valor anterior está lá e é tanto" - em linguagem de programação, o valor anterior *tem* que ser computável - por isso nem dá pra expressar essa função sem ter um valor inicial. (Ok, na verdade pode, mas se fosse chamada ela cairia num caso de recursão infinita e encerraria o programa).

2) Usar um subsistema que implemente objetos que se comportem como símbolos matemáticos. No caso do Python, existe o projeto [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). Ele permite que você especifique objetos em Python com comportamento muito próximo ao de símbolos matemáticos (mas, ainda dentro da sintaxe do Python - por exemplo, a multiplicação vai exigir o operador "*" ). Com o SymPy é possível criar objetos de Python equivalentes a equações como a que você apresenta, e ele poderá fazer uso algébrico da mesma, e calcular um valor numérico através da chamada de métodos específicos.

O SymPy é um projeto grande, feito por profissionais de programação e matemática ao longo de vários anos - é praticamente uma outra linguagem em cima da linguagem Python.

Dai fica claro que você tentar fazer um sistema que possa ele mesmo interpretar sua expressão matemática que faz uso de símbolos e fazer os cálculos a partir dela é algo *bastante* complexo. Pode ser o projeto de uma vida, na verdade.

Em suma: se você tem poucas equações desse tipo, e precisa de uma forma de cálcular os resultados numéricos da mesma usando um computador, traduza uma por uma para a "notação" Python.

Se você vai trabalhar com fórmulas matemáticas, e quer poder trabalhar algebricamente com as equações desse tipo, **pare para estudar o SymPy** - instale, faça os tutoriais e o entenda. Só assim vai poder fazer coisas com ele, por que ee combina dois sistemas de notação complexos - Python e Matemática num terceiro.

E - a não ser que seja um projeto específico para isso, esqueça a abordagem de tentar fazer a interpretação e cálculo de expressões simbólicas de matemática por você mesmo - isso seria reinventar o carro de fórmula 1, e você teria que começar da roda.

Answer (score 1):

Não é nada simples, existem diferentes operações matemáticas e tipos de equações, o que você pode fazer é dividir a string e fazer a avaliação de tudo em loop, como `for` ou `while`.

Não existe nada nativo que faça isso, você pode ir criando aos poucos analisando um por um dos caracteres em algo como:

```
equacao = "Xn = 3,7(xn-1)";

for c in equacao:
    c = c.strip() # Elimina espaços

    if c: # Checa se é vazio
        print(c)
```

Então conforme passa pelo `c` a cada loop você pode avaliar aonde são números, aonde começa e termina os parenteses, exemplo simples com `+` e `-` apenas (testado no *Python 3*):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Exemplo:
    ultimaoperacao = '+';
    ultimovalor = '';
    total = 0;

    def calcularPendente(self):
        if self.ultimovalor == '':
            return None

        valor = int(self.ultimovalor)

        self.ultimovalor = ''

        if self.ultimaoperacao == '+':
           self.total += valor
        elif self.ultimaoperacao == '-':
           self.total -= valor


    def __init__(self, equacao):
        for c in equacao:
            c = c.strip() # Elimina espaços

            if c == '': # Se for vazio i loop irá para o próximo
                continue
            elif c.isnumeric():
                self.ultimovalor += c
                continue

            # calcula os pendentes quando mudar o operador
            self.calcularPendente()

            if c == '+':
                self.ultimaoperacao = '+';
            elif c == '-':
                self.ultimaoperacao = '-';

            self.ultimovalor = '';

        # Após o loop calcula o pendente
        self.calcularPendente()


    def resultado(self):
        return self.total

print( Exemplo("1 + 2").resultado() )
print( Exemplo("10 - 5").resultado() )
print( Exemplo("1 + 1 + 2").resultado() )
print( Exemplo("1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 - 2").resultado() )
```

Exemplo no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/@inphinit/matematica-python)

---

### Bibliotecas

Existem algumas libs prontas que pode facilitar, como https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cexprtk, ela pode ser instalada via `pip`:

```
pip install cexprtk
```

Um exemplo de uso simples:

```
from cexprtk import evaluate_expression

print( evaluate_expression("(5+5) * 23", {}) ) # resultado 230.0
```

Outras libs você pode checar o seguinte link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=Mathematical&submit=search

Comment: Se fosse para eu dizer, diria que o que AP precisa é de recursividade simples e não de análise da expressão matemática numa string. Posso estar enganado, mas esta seria duplicata de qualquer uma que aborde a recursividade.

Comment: exato, Anderson. Um exemplo seria reproduzir a sequencia de  fibbonacci numbers:

 def fibonacci(n):

... a, b = 0, 1

... while b < n:

...      print b,

...      a, b = b, a+b

...

 fibonacci(100) # 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89